# Isolated development environment for react app?

Tags: software-development, react

I want to learn how to use React to build frontend for single page web apps.

However I want to keep my system (Linux mint Sylvia 18.3) "clean" i.e. don't want to have tons of dependencies installed for different apps.

With this in mind I am seeking suggestions for appropriate development environments (e.g. python virtual environments)

I was thinking about using docker to build/run my app inside a container.

My logic is that any dependencies installed would reside inside the container and have no bearing on the "outer" system. Also, I want to learn about Docker anyway.

Am I making sense or have I got the completely wrong idea.

What would you use if you were in my situation.

Comment: Docker is the way to go. For example I have setup node, emberjs sql server and ArangoDB in different containers to play with but I do not have any of those installed on my directly Mac. It is a great way to setup your local environments. I did a little googling and  found this which should get you on your way with react in docker : https://github.com/lopezator/hello-docker-react. (I have not tried this myself btw, so see if it is useful first). It takes a little to adjust your daily workflow to use docker but it is worth it. (plus once you build your image you can share it easily)

Comment: @camba1 Thanks for the advice, I guess i'll go with Docker so as I wanted to start using it anyway. Thanks for the link also, looks promising